# Appending custom HTML to the same div as form_row using twig

Tags: html, css, twig, zurb-foundation

I am displaying form fields that need to also include a custom class block which would display the error in the event incorrect data is entered into a field.

For instance, the code below:

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="small-12 large-6 columns">{{ form_row(form.patientFirstName) }}<small class="error">A valid email address is required.</small></div>
            </div>
```

renders the following:

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="small-12 large-6 columns"><div><label for="form_patientFirstName" class="required"><span class="required" title="This field is required">*</span>

    Patient first name</label><input type="text" id="form_patientFirstName" name="form[patientFirstName]" required="required"    pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" /></div><small class="error">A valid email address is required.</small></div>

            </div>
```

I want the `<small class="error">A valid email address is required.</small>` to be a part of the div that contains the label and input. I have highlighted them both.

Answer (score 1):

As described in the documentation:

> form_row(form.dueDate) - Renders the label, any errors, and the HTML
>   form widget for the given field (e.g. dueDate) inside, by default, a
>   div element;

So you need to render each field by hand as shown below.

```
<div>
    {{ form_label(form.patientFirstName) }}
    <small class="error">A valid email address is required.</small>
    {{ form_errors(form.patientFirstName) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.patientFirstName) }}
</div>
```